# Mount a Device Read Only using Udisk w/ Python

Tags: mount, python, dbus, read-only, udisks

So I am writing a python script that is attempting to use UDisk to mount and unmount devices.  I'm using something like this:

```
disk_dev_func = dbus.Interface(self.device_obj, "org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device")
disk_dev_func.FilesystemUnmount('')
disk_dev_func.FilesystemMount()
```

So the unmount works just fine, my question, however is how to get the last line (mount) to work.  I want to know what arguments I need to mount a device READ ONLY and I cannot for the life of me find any adequate examples of how to do this.

Comment: It's not a proper cut and paste answer, but here's a list of dbus parameters http://cgit.freedesktop.org/udisks/tree/data/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.xml?id=aa02e5fc53efdeaf66047d2ad437ed543178965b

Comment: searched through there and couldnt figure it out either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way to make it work.

Instead of

```
disk_dev_func.FilesystemMount()
```

I use

```
subprocess.call(['udisk', '--mount-options', 'ro', '--mount', '/dev/sdd1'])
```

It seems to mount correctly as read-only with this command.